# Obtain the class datatype of a template parameter?

Tags: java, templates, generics

Given a template class:

```
public class A<T> {}
```

And instantiated as:

```
A<B> a = new A<>();
```

How can I obtain the class datatype of the template parameter?, the equivalent of doing B.class but with the T template parameter so it works for different instantiations.

Background, I'm using JAXB to marshall/unmarshall classes to XML, but to create the `JAXBContext` the a Class object is nedded. This JAXBContext is used in a template class, to solve this I'm currently using a constructor parameter with the Class of the template paramter:

```
public class A<T> {
    public A( Class<T> tClass ){}
}
```

And instantiating it as:

```
A<B> a = new A<>( B.class );
```

Which for me looks a little bit odd, is there a better way?

Comment: The type parameter is erased, the information does not exist at runtime (it's not actually a template). Your solution is the usual idiom.

Comment: I knew about the erasure of template parameters, but being able to perform a cast with the template type `B b = (B) {object};` It sounded strange that I could do a cast but not get the Class for the Class I'm casting to object to!. Thanks.

Comment: That cast actually does not happen right away (You usually get a warning about an "unchecked  cast"), it is deferred until you assign the object to a variable with an actual concrete type. [Here](http://ideone.com/0WLuWe) is a snippet that illustrates this. Note how it still prints "after cast".

Comment: I actually saw the warning, but since I'm forcing the constructor argument to be of type `Class<B>` and casting the objects returned by JAXB to `B`, I think I'm safe; but really interesting 'feature'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one more way to get the type information at runtime.

Type erasure doesn't happen for anonymous classes. So what you can do is while creating the object of class A, just add {} which will make it anonymous class.

```
A<B> aObject = new A<>() {};
```

And you can use the `TypeTokenTree` to get the nth generic parameter.

```
this.typeT = new TypeTokenTree(this.getClass()).getElement(0);
```

There is great [blog post](http://rgomes-info.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/using-typetokens-to-retrieve-generic.html) by Richard describing the complete workflow of this.

The advantage of this approach is that, your client doesn't have to provide the type information every time.

Comment: Very nice article!. Also the con mentioned of 'forgetting to add the anonymous block' is easily avoidable with a factory method, and the constructor not visible.